# Bottleneck encountered returning records for my grid

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, ienumerable

I am using MVC 4.0/C#/EF4.0 and I have a grid page that grabs results that are filtered, sorted and paged. It's filtering results from a table that has 45,000 records. How do I improve performance? This page takes over 30 seconds to load.

```
  var filteredresults = _unitOfWork.ModifiedDataRepository.Get();

            NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);
            int ID = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["sSearch_0"]) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(nvc["sSearch_0"]));
            int TaxYear = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["sSearch_1"]) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(nvc["sSearch_1"]));
            int AdditionalTax = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["sSearch_2"]) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(nvc["sSearch_2"]));

            filteredresults = filteredresults.Where(i => (ID == 0 || i.ID == ID)
                                                                     && (TaxYear == 0 || i.TaxYear == TaxYear)
                                                                     && (AdditionalTax == 0 || i.AdditionalChildTaxCreditAmount == AdditionalTax)
                                                                     );


            int Count = filteredresults.Count();

            string sortCol = param.sColumns.Split(',')[param.iSortCol_0];
            string sortExpression = sortCol + " " + param.sSortDir_0;

            filteredresults = filteredresults.OrderBy(sortExpression);
            filteredresults = from p in filteredresults
                              orderby (sortExpression)
                              select p;

            var parents = filteredresults.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);

            var result = from c in parents.ToList()
                         select new MODIFIED_DATA()
                         {
                             ID = c.ID,
                             TaxYear = c.TaxYear,
                             AdditionalChildTaxCreditAmount = c.AdditionalChildTaxCreditAmount,
                             ArrivalDate = c.ArrivalDate,
                             ChildCareCredit = c.ChildCareCredit,
                             DLN = c.DLN,
                             EftCd = c.EftCd,
                             EicAmt = c.EicAmt,
                             ElfSourceCd = c.ElfSourceCd,
                             FilingStatusCd = c.FilingStatusCd,
                             MakingWorkPayCreditAmount = c.MakingWorkPayCreditAmount,
                             PrimPrisonerNmCd = c.PrimPrisonerNmCd
                         };

            var CustomerPaged = new DataTablePager<MODIFIED_DATA>();

            CustomerPaged.sEcho = param.sEcho;
            CustomerPaged.iTotalRecords = Count;
            CustomerPaged.iTotalDisplayRecords = Count;
            CustomerPaged.aaData = result.ToList();

            return CustomerPaged;
```

Comment: Did you mean 45,000 or 450,000 records? You mis-typed 45,0000 :)

Comment: My fault, I meant 45k..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Obvious slowdowns**

- for each property of `NameValueCollection` which is set, the condition can ommit the `==0` check.
- you are sorting the results 2 times
- using `.Count()`, but this seems to be needed.
- calling unneccessary `.ToList()` on `parents`
- posibly unneccessary call of `.ToList()` on `result`. Here you should check if `CustomerPaged.aaData` can take an `IEnumerable<MODIFIED_DATA>`

**Naming**

- `result` is an `IEnumerable<MODIFIED_DATA>` so the plural should be used -> `results`
- the kind of hungarian notation you use is seen as bad practice
- local variables should be named using `camelCase` casing

**General**

Consider to extract the "index" strings, like "sSearch_0", into class const variables

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Better loadtime now. Any recommendation on the SQL server end? I am basically doing a select on modified_data table here... select using query analayzer takes 30secs to run. Is indexing an option?

Comment: You can ask a new question about the sql query/stored procedure. Sql is also valid for code review.

Comment: Very greatful for the the code review, enjoy your holiday!